# Adding Schema.org 'Brand' in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I have been adding rich snippets to my ecommerce store, and for the most part I have had no problems. For some reason when I go to add in the "brand" that is recommeneded by Google and Google Merchant services I have problems.

I have added this under: http://schema.org/Offer. And by adding it in the script in my header also with no luck.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json" data-resource-group="head_tag" data-resource-code="organization_schema">{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"addressLocality": "",
"addressRegion": "",
"addressCountry": "",
"postalCode": "",
"streetAddress": ""
},
"email": "customerservice@domain.com",
"name": "Comany namee",
"telephone": "company number"
},
    "brand":{
        "@type":"Thing",
        "name":"[manufacture_name]"
    },
</script>
```

```html
<meta itemprop="brand" content="[manufacturer_name]" />
```

```json
"brand":{
    "@type":"Thing",
    "name":"[manufacture_name]"
},
```

The second one just simply isn't detected for some reason.

I have code similar to the meta tag throughout the documnet so I would prefer to keep with that format if possible.

Comment: I searched the page you linked to on schema.org but there's no example where "brand" appears in any JSON that looks like your example. 

Additionally, be sure to wrap the JSON in script tags.

When you say "problems" and "no luck" what are you referring to?

Comment: I added in the script I tried obiviously "" will have the company info tho

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON-LD has syntax errors:

- The `Organization` is closed with `},`, but the `brand` property appears after it.
- A closing `}` is missing.
- There should be no `,` after the last `}`.

So it would be:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress"
  },
  "name": "company name",
  "brand": {
    "@type": "Brand",
    "name": "manufacturer name"
  }
}
```

(Note that I used [`Brand`](https://schema.org/Brand) instead of `Thing`.)

Comment: So That added it under organization, I was trying to add it under product.

Comment: @Cooper: There is no `Product` in the snippet in your question.